# Jquery slideDown / Slide up menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

I ma trying to make a sliding menu.

I want hovering on logo-container to slide it up and when animation is finished slide down menu. When the mouse will be out of logo-container menu will slide up and when animation will be finisded logo will slide down

on mouse hover
1) logo (slideUp)
- wait until animation compleate -
2) menu (slideDown)
when mouse off
1) menu (slideUp)
- wait until animation compleate - 
2) lodo (slideDown)

Html

```
<div id="header">

    <div class="navigation_menu_hide">
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="logo_show">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="http://img2.russia.ru/upimg//news/19986/top2.jpg" alt="">
            <span>Menu</span>             
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#header").hover(function(){

    $('.logo_show').slideUp('300', function(){
        $('.navigation_menu_hide').slideDown('300');
    });
},function(){
    $('.navigation_menu_hide').slideUp('200');

    $('.logo_show').stop(true, true).slideDown('300');
});
```

[Demo - what I have now (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/tj833/1/)

I have made something but have issue with animation compleate waiting

Comment: I think you may want to look for CSS3 animations instead

Comment: When you guys give the votedown must leave the comment. That's not joke! I think this question is good to learn and OP have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with as a solution I tweaked the jQuery a bit [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tj833/16/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.logo_show').hover(function(){
    $(this).slideUp('300');
    $('.navigation_menu_hide').stop(true, true).slideDown('300', function() {

        $('.navigation_menu_hide').mouseleave(function() {   
               $(this).slideUp('200');
              $('.logo_show').slideDown('300');

      }); 
    });
  });
});
```

Hope that is what you were looking for.